# Join user id from one database with user profile data stored in another database with .Net core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am retrieving data over an API and displaying it in my web application as shown:

[image]

The obvious problem being that I need Last Edited By to show the users name, rather than their GUID.

I use Identity Server 4, so UserProfile details are all held in a separate (OAuth) database.

The flow for returning data to the web app is as follows, and I'd like to know how I could return First and Last name from the OAuth database, instead of user IDs (guids)

[image]

My query in the repository at the moment is simply:

```
    public IEnumerable<Survey> GetSurveys()
    {
        var surveys = _context.Surveys
            .Include(s => s.SurveyStatus)
            .ToList();

        return surveys;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe go to the method that actually adds the records to the survey table, add two columns, first and last name, and using the claims on the user adding/updating them - populate first/last name columns.

Then update your query to use those two new columns.

Comment: @JakeJ but if a users name changed in the profile table, their old name would be stuck attached to the survey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are missing the information in your (business) database. First and last name are actually both identity information as business information. This means that first and last name should be part of both the identity model and business model.

To solve this: add a user table (containing userId, first and last name) and update the table with information when a user logs in.

Since you are logging activity of a logged in user, you always have the information you need. So there is no need to query the user table in the Identity Model. For a first setup you may want to create the new table using information from the identity database.

Though information is stored multiple times, it is not redundant. In fact, you would do the same thing when storing information about external logins.

Comment: Thanks, I did think this would be repeating data but you have argued the case well and that's a good point regarding external logins. I think I will add a LastUpdated column in both databases 'UserProfile' tables so when the user logs in the app can check if web LastUpdated is less than OAuth LastUpdated for that user, and only if true will it perform an update to overwrite user details in the web db.

Comment: The drawback of the LastUpdated column is that you'll have to call the user table on each request. I think it would be better to cache the user interaction. It may be just a list in memory of usernames and expiration time (which can be set to x minutes). If cached you don't have to update the table, otherwise you'll only have to check if the values did change. This will save you database calls and additional fields and claims.

Comment: How to intercept the [Authorize] attribute in the web app to then check/update the users table? [Authorize] is what redirects user to login on OAuth and then redirects to the web app on whatever page they were trying to hit.

Comment: You can add middleware (after authentication since this is relevant for authenticated users only), where you get the current UserId and token from the request. Then you can call the UserInfoEndpoint to retrieve the first and last name: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/userinfo.html

Comment: I have the userinfo endpoint set up and working - I use this to insert current user id into the survey table when it is submitted. I am lost on the add middleware aspect though. I will start a new question and post the link here.

Comment: Success! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690300/intercept-asp-net-core-authorize-action-to-perform-custom-action-upon-successful

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when you have an external identity provider, you'll keep certain claims on authenticated users as part of a local profile.

For logging / auditing, you would use their identity key from the external identity provider as well a foreign key to the user's record in your profile table.  I would keep this so that you have access to the correct record in profiles even when they are not logged in (and the record will remain updated for as long as the user continues coming back).

When a user logs in, you can check their claims against your profiles table and update it.  Then when you look at the audit info or logs, the db query would be getting the updated profile information.