# Intercept asp.net core Authorize action to perform custom action upon successful authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an [Authorize] attribute on my web app controller so any endpoints hit ensure user is re-directed to login on OAuth server first (if not already logged in.)

I now want to start writing user claims to the web app db every time a user logs in. To do this I need to have some code that runs on the web app every time a user is successfully logged in / authorised.

I have been given a clue that it involves adding custom middleware.

My Startup ConfigureServices code is currently as follows:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Env = env;
    }

    public IHostingEnvironment Env { get; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddMvc();

        // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.Authority = Configuration["auth:oidc:authority"];                    

                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = !Env.IsDevelopment();
                options.ClientId = Configuration["auth:oidc:clientid"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["auth:oidc:clientsecret"];
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token"; 

                options.Scope.Add(Configuration["auth:oidc:clientid"]);
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;

            });

    }

... []
```

So my question: what code do I need to add, and where, in order to call a method that will contain my custom action?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`OpenIDConnectOptions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L156) class has an [`Events`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L156) property, that is intended for scenarios like this. This `Events` property ([`OpenIdConnectEvents`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events/OpenIdConnectEvents.cs#L54)) has an [`OnTokenValidated`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events/OpenIdConnectEvents.cs#L54) property (`Func<TokenValidatedContext, Task>`), which you can overwrite in order to be notified when a token is, well, validated. Here's some code:

```
options.Events.OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
{
    // Your code here.
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

In the sample code, `ctx` is a [`TokenValidatedContext`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events/TokenValidatedContext.cs), which [ultimately](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/Events/RemoteAuthenticationContext.cs#L33) contains a `Principal` property (`ClaimsPrincipal`): You should be able to use this property to obtain the claims, etc, that you need using e.g. `ctx.Principal.FindFirst(...)`.

As @Brad mentions in the comments, `OnTokenValidated` is called for each request and (based on your own comment), will not contain the UserInfo that you need. In order to get that, you can use [`OnUserInformationReceived`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events/OpenIdConnectEvents.cs#L59), like so:

```
options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = ctx =>
{
    // Here, ctx.User is a JObject that should include the UserInfo you need.
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

`ctx` in this example is a [`UserInformationReceivedContext`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events/UserInformationReceivedContext.cs):It still includes the `Principal` property but also has a `User` property (`JObject`), as I called out in the code with a comment.

Comment: The `OnUserInformationReceived` event is better suited for the OP's needs.  It is executed once on successful login.  The event you've provided is executed on every request.

Comment: If you're using Azure B2C, then this answer shows how to access the OIDC events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58515372/2608

Comment: `OnUserInformationReceived` sounds like exactly what I need, except, unfortunately, I'm using WS-Federation rather than OpenIDConnect, so the `OnUserInformationReceived` event isn't available and there doesn't appear to be an equivalent.