# IdentityServer4 and integration with signinmanager

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4

We are working on an application that uses IdentityServer4, a web api endpoint, a web administration front end, and a mobile application.  We have the web application set up like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddMvc();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services
            .AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("api1");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            });
    }
```

This works and when we call into a controller that has an [Authorize] attribute on it, we get redirected, sign in, return to the calling site, and all is well.

Now we are trying to add authorization into the mix.  I've seen the video where it is shown not to put authorization information into the token and I get that conceptually.  But now I'd like to do something simple in the UI, like show or hide a link based on if the user is signed in or not.  The default _LoginPartial page has something like this:

```
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)) {
  User is signed in
} else {
  User is anonymous
}
```

In order to use SignInManager and UserManager, we'd have to set up the dependency service:

```
services.AddDbContext<Entities.ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<long>>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

But when I do that, it messes up the authorization attribute on the home controller.

How do I, using IdentityServer4, go about testing whether a user is logged in or not and access my role storage in the web application?  I must be missing something that is allowing us to externally authenticate and then turn around and figure out what roles / claims the user is able to be in / use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use things like `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and `User.Identity.IsInRole`, etc. instead. While you can back IdentityServer with ASP.NET Identity, it's important to realize that your MVC app is using IdentityServer, *not* Identity, for authentication and authorization. As such, things like `SignInManager.IsSignedIn` won't work.

Comment: Makes sense.  Is there special coding that needs to be done to get User.Identity.IsInRole to work?  My understanding is that IdentityServer doesn't provide roles directly and that special translations from role claims to the methods that use IsInRole would be required to be written on my part.

Comment: Nope, should all be set via OpenID Connect integration. That's the standard user principal. Roles are just a specific type of claim.

Comment: @Josh there are events you can hook into from the authentication process.  This answer from last week should lead you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/a/49691132/5782634.  Each client app should be responsible for its own authorization (roles and permissions).  Use these events to populate the User with the required information.