# Handle Azure AAD B2C Login

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I have an ASP.NET Core Razor application, and want to parse the ClaimsIdentity claims when the user completes the SignUpSignIn flow.

I would go about and edit the `asp-area="AzureADB2C" asp-controller="Account"` codebehind controller from the _LoginPartial.cshtml but obviously this is injected through the `services.AddAzureADB2C()` line in the `ConfigureServices`

The use case is:

- I have defined Custom Attributes for my Users
- I want to synchronize these to the database when the user logs on, to later run queries against

How can I regsiter an "event handler" for the Login event?

Comment: Please go through this [documents](https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/azure-ad-b2c-onticketreceived-newuser-claim/) on how to insert the User sign up log in to the local database and by using the[`OnTokenValidated`](https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2) event you can log the User sign Log in to the local database

Comment: Thanks, combined with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508727/how-to-add-ontokenvalidated-event-handler-when-using-ad-b2c it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Working code snippet:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, o =>
{
    o.Events.OnTokenValidated += async ctx =>
    {
        var value = ctx.Principal.FindFirst("extension_MyCustomExtensionAttribute").Value;

        // Do stuff
    };
});
```